# Intellij [ Scala + SBT] error while importing SBT project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I want to make a Spark project in Intellij.

But when I create a new project - SCALA -> SBT.
**I haves this error:**

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/><pre>Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.8 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 52 already retrieved (0kB/300ms)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.8: missing sbt.xMain
```

Note: The scala plugins is installed.
**My versions:**
**JAVA**

```
james@james-VirtualBox:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Se
```

**Scala**

```
james@james-VirtualBox:~$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.1 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

And when I try

```
james@james-VirtualBox:~$ sbt -version

    Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.8 ...
    :: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
        confs: [default]
        0 artifacts copied, 52 already retrieved (0kB/153ms)
    Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.8: missing sbt.xMain
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

SBT tries to download it self but can not.
Check your internet connection/firewall.

If that is not the problem, check if there is more than one scala or java version installed. If so uninstall all except one.

If this dose not help check your [sbt repos](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html)

Comment: `0 artifacts copied, 52 already retrieved (0kB/153ms)` he downloaded nothing so there is no connection or the server is down.

Comment: I just saw `james@james-VirtualBox` is your virtual box allowed to connect to the internet?

Comment: I solve the problem. In intelliJ, i change the SBT version and its works.